# How to fix authentication password, when password is rejected?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, authentication, password-recovery

When I try to upgrade, I am prompted for authentication password. I enter the password I have set, but I receive a message saying it is incorrect. The same thing happens when I am prompted to "unlock" for document editing, etc. The password is rejected.

I re-set my password in the root system, but continue to have the same problem.

Comment: "I re-set my password in the root system" the authentication password should be your main user password. `root` is disabled by default. that being said, how did you do this?

Comment: What happens if you try "ubuntu" as your password?

Comment: What commands did you used to change password in terminal ? Give more details. su passwd....

Answer (score 1):

It could be an issue with the keyboard language as I discovered.  When I input my initial password, the keyboard is ENG (GB), but once the OS loads, the keyboard changes to US keyboard layout.  This means that certain special keys (such as " and @) are switched around.